# How to make a timer inside a def funtion/thread

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have been trying to a reaction test the problem is that when i define a variable for time inside a def funtion it later says that that varieble is not defined. I would realy like to know how you define a varieble for time.time() inside a def funtion. The desired outcome is that it should print the time between start and end times.

```
import turtle
import time
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Temp")
wn.setup(width=600,  height=600 )
wn.tracer(0)
wn.bgcolor("blue")

def temp(x, y):
    start = time.time()
    wn.onscreenclick(temp2)
wn.onscreenclick(temp)
def temp2(x, y):
    end = time.time()
    total = end - start
    print (total)
wn.mainloop()
```

here is the specific error code:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\erigo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\erigo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 675, in eventfun
    fun(x, y)
  File "C:/Users/erigo/PycharmProjects/Reactiontest/Reaction_test.py", line 38, in click
    total = end - start
NameError: name 'start' is not defined
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mre]. The error you get is probably not directly related to timers or using the turtle library. If you show the exact error message including traceback we can tell you what the problem is.

Comment: The error is `NameError: name 'a' is not defined` in the line `ms = end - a`. What do you think `a` is? It is not mentioned anywhere else in the code. So the Python interpreter is right to tell you that it doesn't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass the `start` variable from `temp` to `temp2` via the `onscreenclick`.

Here I have used a `lambda` to compose a new function which takes `(x,y)`, but forwards to `temp2` with `start` as well:

```py
import turtle
import time

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Temp")
wn.setup(width=600,  height=600 )
wn.tracer(0)
wn.bgcolor("blue")

def temp(x, y):
    start = time.time()
    wn.onscreenclick(lambda x,y: temp2(x,y,start))

def temp2(x, y, start):
    end = time.time()
    total = end - start
    print (time)

wn.onscreenclick(temp)
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thx for the help it worked good. But as I am trying to learn python could you explain what lampa does or link me something that explains it ofc you dont have to but i would realy appriciate it.

Comment: Just look for lambda in the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Comment: And you should be able to upvote me now.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `click(x,y)` method you have a line `ms = end - a`. The variable `end` was defined in the previous row but the variable `a` is not defined anywhere in the code.
This probable gives you the error.

As to how to create a timer, I think you have a scope problem, I see you create and start the timer in the method `clicked()` but then you want to stop it and calculate the offset in the method `click()`, the best way to do that will be inside a larger class with these functions being methods and the timer being an instance variable. but you could achieve the same result simply by using global variables outside these functions (though this probably isn't very good practice)

Answer (score 0):

So, whenever a variable is defined inside a method/function, its value cannot be accessed from outside that method.

That is why, when you're trying to access `start`, in the line `total = end - start`, the Python interpreter doesn't know what `start` is.

There are a few ways to fix this problem.

1. Move the start and end variables to outside the methods (these are called global variables now, as opposed to method-specific variables):

```py
start = None
end = None
# Defining these variables outside the methods
# will allow you to access them from inside any method

def temp(x, y):
    start = time.time()
    wn.onscreenclick(temp2)
wn.onscreenclick(temp)
def temp2(x, y):
    end = time.time()
    total = end - start
    print (total)
wn.mainloop()
```

2. Use python classes and objects to create a more specific namespace for variables (this is a little advanced, but helps keep your code much cleaner

```py
class Timer:
    def __init__():
        self.start = None
        self.end = None
    def temp(self, x, y):
        self.start = time.time()
        wn.onscreenclick(self.temp2)
    def temp2(self, x, y):
        self.end = time.time()
        print (self.end - self.start)

timer = Timer()

wn.onscreenclick(timer.temp)
```

3. Pass the values as parameters to the methods

```py
start = None
end = None
# Defining these variables outside the methods
# will allow you to access them from inside any method

def temp(x, y):
    start = time.time()
    return start

def temp2(x, y, start):
    end = time.time()
    total = end - start
    print (total)

start = temp(x, y)
temp2(x, y, start)
```

This is not going to be trivial with your code and use-case, but it is possible. @quamrana has given an example of how